# Is there a simple way to create an NSAttributedString using markup on iOS?

Tags: ios, ios6, nsattributedstring

I would simply to add bold or italic to portions of my text. Is there some built in parse that makes this simple, as most the examples I've seen show about a page worth of code, which requires doing substring range calculations on the string. Ideally, I could do something like this:

```
label.attributedText = [NSAttributedString initWithXXX:@"Some **bold** and *italic text*"];
```

Comment: There is no built in way.  DTCoreText can generate an NSAttributedString from HTML but the last time I checked, it wasn't set up for UIKit (although it is not that hard to convert it yourself, it is all just changing the attribute key names from kCT*whatever* to NS*whatever*)

Answer (score 1):

[MGPushParser](http://www.bigpaua.com/MGBoxKit/docs/Classes/MGMushParser.html) in [MGBoxKit](https://github.com/sobri909/MGBox2) supports this for bold, italics, underlining, and monospacing, and coloured text.

```
"**bold**, //italics//, __underlined__, `monospaced`, and {#0000FF|blue}"
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText supports all the markup you can think of ^^

even css to NSAttributedString is possible.

See the attached Examples. It works fine with UIKit